# Как перенести текст только на 2 строчки и скрыть

Tags: javascript, html, css

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Не знаю как после переноса текста на следующую строчку остановить перенос и поставить троеточие. Для переноса использую white-space: pre-line, но текст переносится без остановки весь. А надо перенести 2 строчки, и оставить ...

```css
.text {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: pre-line;    
}
```

```html
<span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>
```

Comment: `text-overflow` не имеет эффекта при `white-space: pre-line`. Только при `white-space: nowrap`

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так

```css
.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>
```